# A javascript equivalent for toDictionary (c#)

Tags: javascript

I made a function that should ease the making of new objects out of objects or arrays.

I extended underscore so thats why the _.

```
        _.dictionary = function (obj, keyIteratee, valueIteratee) {
            var newObj = new Object();
            if (Array.isArray(obj)) {
                var length = obj.length;
                for (var index = 0; index < length; index++) {
                    newObj[keyIteratee(obj[index], index)] = valueIteratee(obj[index], index);
                }
            } else { //assume its an object
                var keys = Object.keys(obj);
                var length = keys.length;
                for (var index = 0; index < length; index++) {
                    newObj[keyIteratee(obj[keys[index]], keys[index])] = valueIteratee(obj[keys[index]], keys[index]);
                }
            }
            return newObj;
        };
```

usage:

```
_.dictionary(inputArray, function(s) { return s.Name; }, function(s) { return s.Value; });
_.dictionary(inputObject, function(s,i) { return i; }, function(s) { return s.Inner.Value; });
```

Is this a good way to tackle such a thing? am i missing something?

Comment: I would say that something like this is much closer to "equivalent" with the C# method: https://jsfiddle.net/sf4pusou/

Comment: but this wouldn't work with dictionaries/js objects. and would reduce it. what if i would want to enrich or encapsulate the data? this wouldn't work

Comment: Correct, but a data source that implements IEnumerable in C# is a collection - not an object. I guess what I'm trying to say is that your title is a bit misleading since you are pretty far from what ToDictionary actually does. That being said I could still give you some feedback on your current implementation if you like

Comment: this is true, but then dictionaries get serialized as object notation if you JSONify them, and since ienumerable does not exist in javascript. Yes, if you could that would be nice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When providing an object, I don't think it makes sense to pass the index into the callbacks. Rather, pass in the current key.

Also, I think `reduce` reads much clearer here:

```js
_.dictionary = function (source, keyGenerator, valueGenerator) {
    if (Array.isArray(source)) {
        return source.reduce(function (output, value, index) {
            output[keyGenerator(value, index)] = valueGenerator(value, index);
            return output;
        }, {});
    }

    return Object.keys(source).reduce(function (output, key) {
        output[keyGenerator(source[key], key)] = valueGenerator(source[key], key);
        return output;
    }, {});
};
```

See it here in action: https://jsfiddle.net/e4g4p7wy/